# Chrome not loading images

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am using the latest (as of now 5.0.375.70) version of Chrome. Randomly when I visit websites images will load up fully then as soon as the page finishes loading the images blank out to the broken image icon. When I right click and 'open image in new tab' the image loads fine.

The latest Firefox and Internet Explorer load it fine. It has been happening for awhile now, with and without extensions. Sadly right now the only page I have that does it is from catatar :(

Windows 7 64bit
Chrome 5.0.375.70

Example of broken images:

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/1si0bq.png]

Direct link:

> http://catatar.com/the-very-best-places-for-a-cat-nap/

Comment: Looks like a problem with the site and not Chrome itself--I'm having the same issue you are on that site.

Comment: How can it be an issue with the site if FF/IE load it fine. Maybe an issue with webkit then?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 6.0.437.3 and even there it's broken. I've filed a report about this as well.